# Can't get Resque and Sentry to work together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, sentry

I have a Rails app that uses Resque. I added Sentry to the app and, independently of Resque, Sentry seems to work fine. But Sentry doesn't seem to be catching errors inside of Resque jobs.

Here's my Resque initializer file:

```
# used in routes
require 'resque/server'

require 'resque/failure/multiple'
require 'resque/failure/redis'
require 'resque-sentry'

# Change redis settings according to env variable
uri = URI.parse(ENV['REDIS_URL'] || 'redis://localhost:6379')

REDIS_INSTANCE = Redis.new(
  host: uri.host,
  port: uri.port,
  password: uri.password
)

# use a separate namespace
RESQUE_NAMESPACE = "App::#{Rails.env}"

# This will initialize the connection to redis
Resque.redis = REDIS_INSTANCE
Resque.redis.namespace = RESQUE_NAMESPACE

Resque::Failure::Multiple.classes = [Resque::Failure::Redis, Resque::Failure::Sentry]
Resque::Failure.backend = Resque::Failure::Multiple

Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

Any ideas as to what I can do to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

Sentry offers the [sentry-resque](https://rubygems.org/gems/sentry-resque) gem which will automatically insert a custom middleware and error handler to capture exceptions from workers.

See: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-ruby/tree/master/sentry-resque